# Style every second row with rows hidden

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a structure like this

```
<div>
    <div class="field">Test</div>
    <div class="field">Test</div>
    <div class="field hidden">Test</div>
    <div class="field">Test</div>
    <div class="field">Test</div>
</div>
```

I want to style every second row with a different background like this:

```
.field:nth-child(even){background:#f4f4f4;}
.hidden{display:none;}
```

The third row is not visible but css stil counts it, so the Design is broken.

The obvious solution with `:not(.hidden)` before `:nth-child...` does not work. I've allready found a selecteor which is [not supported yet](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo): `:nth-child(even of :not([hidden]))`

Do you know how to achieve this with current css?

Comment: the only solution is that selector not yet supported or use JS

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for the link to the duplicate. No idea why I didn't find it. I guess I have to use JS then. Kind regards.